# Замена значения для SortedList при известном ключе и индексе. C#

Tags: c#

Не работает замена значения для SortedLista.

```
public static void SetCell(SortedList<SelectedCell, CellInterior> data, SelectedCell cell, CellInterior meta)
    {
        data[cell].Set(meta.add0, meta.add1); // Ничего не происходит
        data[cell].add0 = meta.add0; // Ошибка Не удалось изменить 
                                     // возвращаемое значение, т. к. оно не является переменной
    }
```

(Исправлено) Однако поиск ключа работает некорректно, в т.ч методом SortedList.IndexOfKey(). Хотя CompareTo реализован.

```
public struct SelectedCell :IComparable<SelectedCell> 
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
        public int CompareTo(SelectedCell other)
        {
            if (this.X == other.X && this.Y == other.Y)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else if (this.X > other.X)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.X < other.X)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else if (this.X == other.X && this.Y > other.Y)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.X == other.X && this.Y < other.Y)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        public SelectedCell(int x, int y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }
    }
```

При дебаге почему то не все ключи подаются на сравнение(сравнивается примерно 20 ключей из 900).

Помогите заменить значение.

Comment: У вас `CompareTo` никогда не возвращает `-1`. Это не может  быть правильно. Исправляйте.

Comment: Исправил. Ошибка все так же встречается

Comment: Покажите новый код. Возможно, вы неправильно исправили.

Comment: обновил код выше.

Comment: Ну вот, снова неправильно. Если у вас сравниваются (1, 0) и (1, 1), кто будет больше? А если сравнивать (1, 1) и (1, 0)?

Comment: С последним изменением тот же контрпример.

Comment: Спасибо большое, CompareTo() заработал. Все уперлось в незнание принципов его работы. Но все же значение в SortedListе по заданному ключу заменяться не хочет.

Comment: Окей, `CompareTo` выглядит хорошо. Теперь вопрос: а не меняются ли X и Y после попадания объекта в SortedList? Попробуйте убрать публичный сеттер для них.

Comment: Кстати, обычно CompareTo реализуют как-то так: https://pastebin.com/muvJJDse

Comment: Ах, у вас мутабельная структура! Ну да, это зло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, `CellInterior` — структура, а не класс.

Код

```
data[cell].Set(meta.add0, meta.add1);
```

работает следующим образом. Он вызывает оператор `[]`, который выдаёт вам на руки *копию* структуры — не забываем, что структуры возвращаются по значению!

Затем вы вызываете мутирующий метод на копии структуры, но на оригинале структуры это не отражается.

Во втором случае вы пытаетесь у копии структуры поменять свойство, и компилятор даже специально предупреждает вас о том, что бы делаете неправильно.

---

Чтобы работало, нужно не забыть вызвать сеттер:

```
var v = data[cell];
v.Set(meta.add0, meta.add1);
data[cell] = v;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Через вызов сетера все получилось)

Comment: @РустамХалилов: Пожалуйста!